# Estimates on density for Stokes equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities, sobolev-spaces

Consider a bounded, smooth domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and in there the Stokes equations

$\nabla p(\rho)-\Delta u=\rho f\\
\operatorname{div}(\rho u)=0\\
u\restriction_{\partial \Omega}=0$

where the pressure take the barotropic form $p=\rho^\gamma$ for some $\gamma>3$ and $f\in L^\infty$. Imagine that $u\in H^1_0$ and $\rho\in L^{2\gamma}$ and that the weak gradient $\nabla\rho$ exists. Then from the second equation one can derive the following inequality:

$\|u\cdot \nabla\rho\|_{\frac{2\gamma}{\gamma+1}}\leq c$

My question now is if one can bound the density gradient by this knowledge, i.e. can we achieve an inequality like $\|\nabla\rho\|_p\leq c$ for a suitable $p$? In best case, can we set $p=\gamma$?

I would be grateful for any hint.